# React Native - Why are my Conditional If/If Else Statements Never Passing?

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements

I'm new to React Native and Javascript, but I cannot find anything online to help me with this problem that I am having.

My "macSong" functions if statements never pass and I'm unsure as to why, I feel like the logic behind the code is sound, yet my console is still outputting "Selected Item is Unknown" because all of the if else statements are "not true" when at least one of them should be true if the dropdown menu has been used before pressing the button. My macSong function is just above my Stylesheet, at the bottom of my code.

If anyone can help me that would be amazing, thank you in advance and be sure to let me know if you need any more information to help you answer my question!

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import SearchableDropdown from 'react-native-searchable-dropdown';

var items =[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Happy Music'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Sad Music'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Chill Music'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Hype Music'
    }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.screen }>
      <Fragment>
        {/* Title */}
        <View style={ styles.title }>
          <Text> Which Mac Miller Song Matches Your Mood? </Text>
        </View>
          {/* Single Dropdown Menu */}
          <SearchableDropdown
            onItemSelect={(item) => {
              const items = this.state.selectedItems;
              this.setState({ selectedItems: [...items, item]});
            }}
            containerStyle={{ padding: 25, alignSelf: 'center' }}
            onRemoveItem={(item, index) => {
              const items = this.state.selectedItems.filter((sitem) => sitem.id !== item.id);
              this.setState({ selectedItems: [...items, item] });
            }}
            itemStyle={{
              padding: 10,
              marginTop: 2,
              backgroundColor: '#ddd',
              borderColor: '#bbb',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderRadius: 5,
            }}
            itemTextStyle={{ color: '#222' }}
            itemsContainerStyle={{ maxHeight: 140 }}
            items={items}
            defaultIndex={''}
            resetValue={false}
            textInputProps={
              {
                placeholder: "What kind of music do you want to hear?",
                underlineColorAndroid: "transparent",
                style: {
                    padding: 12,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#ccc',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                },
              }
            }
            listProps={
              {
                nestedScrollEnabled: true,
              }
            }
        />

      {/* Button */}
      <View style={ styles.button }>
        <Button
          title="Press me for a Mac Miller song!"
          onPress={() => 
            this.macSong()}
        />
      </View>
      </Fragment>
      </View>
    );
  }

  /* Different Mood Function */
  macSong() {
    console.log(this.state.selectedItems)
    if (this.state.selectedItems.some(item => item.name === 'Happy Music')) {
      let songs = ['best day ever', 'kool aid & frozen pizza', 'nikes on my feet'];
      let song = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
      console.log(song);
    } else if (this.state.selectedItems.some(item => item.name === 'Sad Music')) {
        let songs = ['self care', 'ROS', 'stay', 'whats the use'];
        let song = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
        console.log(song);
    } else if (this.state.selectedItems.some(item => item.name === 'Chill Music')) {
        let songs = ['good news', 'claymation', 'the star room'];
        let song = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
        console.log(song);
    } else if (this.state.selectedItems.some(item => item.name === 'Hype Music')) {
        let songs = ['donald trump', 'remember', 'weekend'];
        let song = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
        console.log(song);
    } else {
        console.log("Selected Item is Unknown");
    }
  }
}

{/* StyleSheet */}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  title: {
    padding: 30,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.selectedItems` is an array of objects of the following form:

```
{ id: Number, name: String }
```

If we look at your if statements, your conditionals look like:

```
if (this.state.selectedItems.includes('Happy Music')) {
```

Your array of objects will never include a plain string. You want to check if in includes an object with the name of that String. You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for that. Something like this:

```
if (this.state.selectedItems.some(item => item.name === 'Happy Music'))
```

Hopefully that gets you back to a working state. Peeking at your code it looks like you have opportunity to simplify this logic after this.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now, no matter which dropdown i have selected, it always outputs a happy song in the console. I will update my code in the question with what I currently have

Comment: I just figured it out, Its because my `selectedItems` was a list instead of a string, I will update the code again, but how would I be able to simplify the logic?

Comment: So I changed this `this.state = {
      selectedItems: []
    }` to this `this.state = {
      selectedItems: ''
    }` and if i go through the order, hype, then chill, then sad, then happy (basically backwards from my if statements, then it works perfectly, but if i chose anything else after choosing happy, it will output a happy song. Do you know how i could fix this?

Comment: `this.state = { selectedItems: [] }` seemed correct. You want `selectedItems` to be an array

Answer (score 0):

First, you are calling `macSong()` with no arguments on button press, but on its definition you have an argument `macSong(selectedArguments) { ... }`. This is not needed because you are grabbing `this.state.selectedItems` within your function. So the correct would be `macSong() { ... }`.

Then, it should be `this.state.selectedItems.map(item => item.name).includes("Happy Music")` etc., because `item` is an object that has `name` as a property, and when you check if an object `includes("string")` you need to check an array of strings (which `map()` will do).

Comment: The `selectedItems` parameter can safely be removed, it's not used. Similarly `macSong` could be passed directly in `onPress`, `onPress={this.macSong}` instead of making a fat arrow function that only calls another function with no arguments

Comment: Don't think there's any need for `map` here unless RN doesn't support `some`. `map + include` will iterate over the array twice whereas you could just once using `some`

Comment: True, `some` is preferred

Comment: `map` is not working, giving me an error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined." How would I use `some`?

Comment: Actually, I am getting that same error with `some` as well, Why am i getting that error?

Comment: My bad, it is `this.state.selectedItems` not `this.selectedItems`